# Use GPS with iBeacon in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gps, ibeacon

is it possible to use GPS with iBeacon when app is in background? 
I need to start update gps location when iPhone detect iBeacon only through 180s, I do something like this but it doesn't work :/

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if !isInForeground {
        extendBackgroundTime()
    }
    print(wasBeaconDetected)

    for beacon in beacons {
        if beacon.rssi < -10 {
            wasBeaconDetected = true
            nearbyBeacons.append(beacon)
        }
    }
    print(beacons)
    currentLocation = manager.location!.coordinate
    if firstRegionDetected == "" {
        firstRegionDetected = region.identifier
    } else if firstRegionDetected == region.identifier {
        analyzeScan(nearbyBeacons, currentLocation)
    }
}
```

of course I start monitoring when determine State

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
    if isInBackground {
        extendBackgroundTime()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Background Modes>Location updates enabled in your apps capabilities?

Comment: Yes it is, I also requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Comment: You need use startMonitoring instead of making ranging in background you must not do ranging with beacons